# CSS is getting cached

Tags: css

The **CSS** file is some how getting cached.
I tried with reloading **CTRL+F5** deleting whole cache it didn't work.
I am able to access new version only if i change its version like ** **.

I am able to access the file even after renaming it. 

I renamed it **file.css to file-1.css** but still i can access **file.css but I cannot access file.css?v=1**
I changed contents of css like.
`.section{
    width:257px;
 }`

Later i changed this to.
`.section{
    width:157px;
 }`

but code is not getting reflected even after hard refresh

Comment: You probably didn’t rename it where it’s actually getting served from.

Comment: you can see the files requesting for the server in `network` section in developers tools it may help you

Comment: No i checked the path and confirmed